# How to read in API data only of a particular type?

Tags: javascript

My script reads in data from a website API (https://api.discogs.com/) for instance https://api.discogs.com/releases/249504

```
"identifiers": [{"type": "Barcode", "value": "5012394144777"}...]
```

I want it to read in      identifiers of type      Barcode only. Right now I can see that it's reading in the entire array and that's not what I want; it's 'casting the net too wide'/

```
  var barcode = data.identifiers;

const barcode = data.identifiers || []

const barcode = data.identifiers.type == "Barcode" || []
```

I think this is an array of objects, but how do I target just the data I want? TIA.

Edit: I'm pretty sure that "Barcode" will be entered as a string in quotes, because one of the other possible types of identifiers is "Label Code", which surely must be entered as a string seeing as it contains a space!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the filter function:

```
> data = [{'type':'Barcode', value:'A'}, {'type':'Matrix', 'value':'B'}]
[ { type: 'Barcode', value: 'A' }, { type: 'Matrix', value: 'B' } ]
> data.filter(x => x.type == 'Barcode')
[ { type: 'Barcode', value: 'A' } ]
```

If you didn't know about the built-in filter method, you could also do something like this with a for loop:

```
const b = []
for (x of data) {
  if (x.type == 'Barcode') {
    b.push(x)
  }
}
```